# How can i add eraser cocos2d?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

This is my cocos2d screen. And i wanna add eraser.(not clean just erase the lines like an eraser).The background is image. So it shouldn't be erased.How can i do that?

[image: this is screenshot]

Edit: i used  this code. https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/smooth-drawing

Comment: That depends entirely on your drawing code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yatanadam, I think your original question is quite broad and to be able to solve all your problem it would require someone to understand all the code of the sample you want to use. You would find an answer faster if you asked for specific pieces of the code or provided more information about the sample.

I did a quick check and in the class LineDrawer.m there is a method called draw, that first calculates the points needed for the curves you want and then calls drawLines to do the actual job of drawing. You could try to calculate which points need to be eliminated and then delete them from the array points. Every time the user touches the screen to erase you would need to delete points from the array to make it work.

Still, what you are asking requires a deeper understanding of the sample

Comment: I follow your idea for adding and removing points from array.But can you give idea to me for that how to original image will draw.